# Variation on definition of a derivative

Tags: calculus

Suppose that a function is differentiable at $x=2$ and
$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac {x^3 f(x)-24}{x-2} = 28 $, find $f(2)$ and $f'(2)$.

Not sure where to even start on this since it doesn't fall into the standard format for the definition of a derivative.

Comment: Can you do the first part (find $f(2)$)?

Comment: since the denominator is going to zero and the limit is defined, the numerator should also approach zero.  This gives $f(2)=3$. We use hospital rule  and get the answer

Comment: Note that if $g(x):=(x^3f(x)-24)/(x-2)$ is differentiable then also $f(x)=(24+(x-2)g(x))/x^3$ is differentiable at every $x\not = 0$. Then uses de l'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 4):

Since the denominator's limit is zero, it must be the case that the limit of the numerator should be $0$ and hence, $\lim_{x\to 2}x^3f(x)-24=0$. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to2}f(x)=3$ and since $f'(2)$ exists, the function is continuous and $f(2)=3$. Similarly, the given expression means that the derivative of $g(x)=x^3f(x)$ at $x=2$ is equal to 28 and, using the chain rule, you can recover $f'(x)=-1$.

Comment: The function is in fact continuous. Otherwise it wouldn't be differentiable.

Comment: OK, I want to understand this.  I didn't know that if the denominator limit doesn't exist then the limit of the numerator should be 0!!!!  Is there a theorem or something you can point me to that explains this?

Comment: Also, one could use the product rule.

Comment: @user163862 It follows from what we know. We know that if the denominator of a fractional function vanishes at a point and yet a (finite) limit exists there, then the numerator couldn't be nonzero (otherwise, the limit should be infinite).

Comment: That makes total sense now.

Comment: Thanks @Allawonder, you are right, just edited the post.

Comment: @user163862: The easiest way to make the argument rigorous is to use the law for products of limits: if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to A$ (a finite limit, not $\pm \infty$) and $g(x) \to 0$, then it follows that $f(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \cdot g(x) \to A \cdot 0 = 0$. This is a standard trick used to prove, for example, that a differentiable function is automatically continuous too.

Comment: By the way, @Behrouz, you should say that the denominator's limit **is** zero, not that the limit **goes to** zero. The denominator goes to the limit, and that limit is the number zero which isn't going anywhere, it's just sitting there on the number line waiting for the denominator to approach it. (So to speak.)

Answer (score 1):

You can Taylor-expand $f$ to get:
$$f(x) = f(2) + (x-2)f'(2) + o(x-2).$$
Using this expression, and the knowledge that the limit is well-defined and equal to 28 at $x=2$, can you finish the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set $g(x):=(x^3f(x)-24)/(x-2)$. Note that the denominator of $g$ is an infinitesimal at $2$. Since the limit of $g$ exists finite at $2$, the numerator of $g$ should also approach zero. Thus, $f(2)=3$.

For the derivative, note that if $g$ is differentiable then also $f(x)=(24+(x-2)g(x))/x^3$ is differentiable at every $x\not = 0$ (in particular, around $x=2$). Then uses de l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: I'd like to understand this better.  When you say the denominator of g is infintesimal at 2, that doesn't seem right to me.  When x=2, then the denominator is precisely zero, correct?  Not small, but exactly, precisely 0.  As it approaches 2 it gets small, but at 2 the denominator is zero....right?

Comment: Right. Let me try to explain you better. By definition, a function $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ with $U$ open subset of $\mathbb{R}$  is infinitesimal at a point $x_0\in U$ if, and only if, $\lim_{x\to x0} f(x)=0$. It can happen that $f(x_0)\not =0$ but $\lim_{x\to x0} f(x)=0$. However, if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $f$ is infinitesimal if, and only if, $f(x_0)=0$.